# In which Fringe episode did Walter enter the wrong house and slept there for three days?

Tags: episode-identification, fringe

In one of *Fringe*'s episodes, (I think in the 2nd or 3rd season), Walter states:

> I once went into the wrong house by mistake and slept there for three days.

1. Which one was this?
2. Give a basic outline of what led up to this?

Comment: To add to Colin's answer, [Fringepedia](http://fringepedia.net) is a pretty good resource. It has the full transcript of most episodes, in case you want search for a quote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Season 3, Episode 8 (Entrada). From [Walter Bishop's Wikia page](https://fringepedia.net/wiki/Walter_Bishop):

> "It's perfectly understandable, son. In the 'Seventies', I innocently
>   wandered into the wrong home and it was three days before I realized
>   my mistake. And unlike Olivia, the woman with whom I was sharing a bed
>   didn't look like my wife at all." - (to Peter, consoling him on the
>   embarassing deception levied by Bolivia)

Comment: A funny remark by a great character. I miss Dr Bishop :(

Comment: ...and an awesome episode of Fringe as well.